# Azure Sql Column Level Encryption Error - Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, always-encrypted

I am working POC of API to store/retrieve some sensitive information to/from SQL database. API uses EF core for DB operations. I have configured the column level encryption with Azure KeyVault provider.
Master key is getting generated in KeyVault.

**EF Configuration Reference**

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/60420382/ef-core-decryption-of-sql-column-level-encryption

I need to use managed identity to access encryption MasterKey form KeyVault. Below is the code to initialize KeyVault Provider and get token token using the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication library to access KeyVault.

```
private static void InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider()
    {
        SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider =
          new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

        Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers =
          new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();

        providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);
        SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").ConfigureAwait(false);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Access token is getting generated successfully.

In addition to master key, I am storing connection string in KeyVault and configured KeyVault provider using Managed identity to retrieve connection string from KeyVault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I deployed the Api App in Azure and enabled the Identity. I used this system generated ObjectId to add KeyVault access policy to allow Api to access KeyVault.
I have provided the required permissions to keys such as get,wrapKey,unwrapKey,sign,verify,list

Now I can access the connection string and able connect to database. But when I am trying to save the record in database I am getting below error.

Looks like with a generated token I am not able to access the KeyVault. Am I missing anything?. Please help.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at DbEncryptionApi.Controllers.MedicalController.SavePatientRecord(PatientDto patient) in D:\Data\Projects\DbEncryptionApi\DbEncryptionApi\Controllers\MedicalController.cs:line 34
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: 'C6-C8-F6-58-A0-DE-6F-68-73-9F'.
One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized')

Inner Exception 2:
KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Answer (score -1):

From the error it looks like you might not have the column encryption key properly configured and linked to the master key in KeyVault.

I suggest you review the setup of the column encryption in the database  - perhaps using the wizard to verify the setup to KeyVault as a first step.

Comment: `I deployed the Api App in Azure and enabled the Identity.`